# Output object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, object

I have an ObjectHtmlInputElement:

```
for($array as $a){
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$a.'">';
}
```

Javascript:

```
function myForm(){
 var theForm=document.getElementById("myCheck");
 var a = theForm.elements['check[]'];

 for( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(a[i].checked){
             alert( a[i].value );
             return true;
            }
  }
}
```

This script checks if atleast one checkbox is checked then return true(there can also be more checkboxeses checked).What i need is to output in the alert() , each checkbox that have been checked(each object value that passes 'a[i].checked'). a[i].value , outputs only the first value, so i need something else.

**Based on 'dec' and 'vijay' s answer i managed to find a solution:**

```
var checkedCheckboxes="";
for( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[i].checked){
        checkedCheckboxes += a[i].value;
        }
    }
for( var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(a[i].checked){
            alert('Checked: ' + checkedCheckboxes);
            return true;
            }
}
```

**Indeed the loop was stopped because of return true as dec said.And the solution was to make another loop,and insert all values in a variable so i can use it in the alert.**

Comment: So have a flag inside the function and return that flag just _after_ the loop. Inside the loop you just adjust the flag.

Comment: Why not build a string up in the loop and then, if the string has content, alert?

Comment: some examples please? i'm kind of new in javascript

Comment: Maybe you want to elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achive (and not so much how you want to achieve it). Maybe it's an XY-Problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @VolkerK , i already said what i'm trying to achieve.I need to output the checkbox values that are checked, in an alert

Comment: Ok, then you might want to elaborate on why you want to output it (or not, that's up to you of course - but I have a strong feeling that you're actually trying to achieve somethign else. A for loop with alert() in it ....sorry, that doesn't sound like the final step, the goal you want to achieve)

Comment: @VolkerK , of course that's not the final goal.But if i manage to deal with this issue,then it's all done.

Comment: Sorry but I`ve tested your code, and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/ut36k49x/13/

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira , and will never work...this is just a sample so you can understand the idea of the issue.I won't post the entire code,because i dont need you to solve my problem but to learn how to solve it myself.

Comment: I said it's working. check the link I gave you. If you want to test the other checks after the first founded, just remove 'return true' as @dec has answered.

Comment: if you solved it, please don't forget to accept the right answer, or post your own answer on how you solved it if isn't any of the answers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first value seems to match `a[i].checked` and then you return and no other element is tested. So remove `return true`.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you can do:

```
function isThereAtLeastOneCheckActive() {
    var res = false
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) { 
            res = true
            alert(this.val()) 
            // .text() can also be used
        }
    })
    return res
}
```

As you are beggining, maybe you find strange the absense of ;
There is no need for them in js: https://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: i would like to not change the function since all that is blocking me is this little problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myForm() {
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var a = theForm.elements['check[]'];
    var checkedCheckboxes = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].checked) {
            checkedCheckboxes += a[i].value + ", ";
        }
    }
    if (checkedCheckboxes.length > 0) alert(checkedCheckboxes);
    return checkedCheckboxes.length > 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5upLprk/1/

Comment: i just update my answer.take a look please.I changed my code with some of yours but is still showing only the first value.